# Scrapy following sibling confusion?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to scrap a site with HTML like this

```html
<a name="aaaaaaaaa">
  <h2>ggggggggggggg</h2>
</a>
<h3 class="subheader"> head a </h3>
<div>
  <label>key 1</label>
  <span> val 1 </span>
</div>
<div>
  <label>key 2</label>
  <span> val 2 </span>
</div>
<h3 class="subheader"> head b </h3>
<div>
  <label>key 3</label>
  <span> val 3 </span>
</div>
<div>
  <label>key 4</label>
  <span> val 4 </span>
</div>
```

I want to make a dictionary of following structure

```
spec_dict  {
      'head a': {
                'key 1': 'val 1'
                'key 2': 'val 2'
                }
      'head b': {
                'key 3': 'val 3'
                'key 4': 'val 4'
                }           
            }
```

I'm having problems with identifying which divs containing keys and values is part of which heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try @alecxe's code first.
I believe its more pythonic

I think this will solve the problem

```
all_children = response.xpath('//*') # Mathches everything in that div
key_children = response.xpath('//h3') #Matches the h3 nodes
spec_dict = dict()
sp_dict = dict()
title_count = 0
spec_count = 0
spec_key = None
while spec_count < len(all_children):
    if title_count < len(key_children) and all_children[spec_count].extract() == key_children[title_count].extract(): # so its the same node in all_children and key_children
        spec_key = key_children[title_count].xpath('normalize-space(./text())').extract()[0]
        title_count += 1
    else:
        if spec_key:
            key = all_children[spec_count].xpath('normalize-space(./label/text())').extract()[0]
            val = all_children[spec_count].xpath('normalize-space(./span/text())').extract()[0]
            sp_dict[key] = val
            spec_dict[spec_key] = sp_dict
    spec_count += 1
```

Comment: Upvoted for pointing to @alecxe's solution. In addition to being pythonic, the latter is more obvious in how it solves the problem (through xpath `preceding-sibling::h3`, which looks very appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler idea.

Iterate over all `div` elements having `label` and `span` elements and get the first preceding `h3` sibling element. Collect the information into a `defaultdict`:

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict
In [2]: result = defaultdict(dict)
In [3]: for div in response.xpath("//div[label and span]"):
            label = div.xpath("./label/text()").extract()[0]
            span = div.xpath("./span/text()").extract()[0]
            key = div.xpath("./preceding-sibling::h3[1]/text()").extract()[0]

            result[key][label] = span   

In [4]: dict(result)
Out[4]: 
{u' head a ': {u'key 1': u' val 1 ', u'key 2': u' val 2 '},
 u' head b ': {u'key 3': u' val 3 ', u'key 4': u' val 4 '}}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Its very clear, clean and right accurate.